# Calculate a boolean result to show whether a pair of events were matched or not in Esper

Tags: esper, complex-event-processing

I am trying to create an EPL statement that will show whether an order was successful or not.

The statement should match a purchase with a payment, based on an ID of the purchase. The result should contain the ID of the purchase and a Boolean value, which indicates whether a purchase was matched with a payment.

I have got the statement below to return true when a successful match is made. However, I would also like to return a false when a purchase exits the 30 second time window without being matched to a payment.

```
SELECT Purchase.purchaseId AS purchaseId, true AS successful
FROM Purchase.win:time(30), Payment.win:time(30) 
WHERE Purchase.purchaseId = Payment.purchaseId
```

It would also be nice if the order that the events came in didn't matter. For example, if a payment came before an purchase.

Answer (score 1):

Use an outer join instead.

Something like this:

```
SELECT Purchase.purchaseId AS purchaseId, s2 is not null as successfull
FROM Purchase.win:time(30) as s1 left outer join Payment.win:time(30) as s2
on s1.purchaseId = s2.purchaseId
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. This almost does what I want. However, as far as I can see, there will be two output events for each purchase: one when the purchase comes in and another when it is matched with a payment. Is there a way to stop it generating the first output event?

Comment: Yes, there are two streams. You can't stop stream, but you may register UpdateListener/Subscriber to one of then.